# It's possible to load a home.php web site page while user using a landing page?

Tags: php, ajax, performance

I have a index.php (its a video)

when the user is in index.php and seeing the video, its possible to load the home.php (its a portfolio web site and its a little slow, because i have many images)

Comment: We have no idea where to go from this, can you please post your source code?

Comment: Are you trying to load two pages at once? A frame perhaps, if you were stuck in the 90's.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i don't need to post code. The question is simple. Load 2 pages at once. While a user is at index.php I want that web site load the home.php. Is that possible?

Comment: Let me guess. Are you want to speed up the home.php by caching the images while user is watching the video?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images

Comment: L.C. Echo Chan, yes correct

Answer (score 0):

You can't load two PHP files at once.

Instead, you can use either JavaScript or jQuery to preload contents.

See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728261/is-it-possible-to-preload-page-contents-with-ajax-jquery-technique)

Comment: There is no way to load 2 pages at once? (i don't know why I receive negative for question)

Comment: No, I don't think there's any way to load two .php file at once.